# SSRS report - open hyperlinks in new tab

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have spent tons of time trying to figure out how to open hyperlinks from SSRS reports into new tabs without Javascript. I found rc:LinkTarget=_blank parameter that should fix the issue changing all "target=_top" to target="_blank". But it's not happening.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show an example of what your URL looks like now.

Comment: href="http://www.google.com" target="_top". Although, in the report it looks like this: <a href=""http://www.google.com"" target=""_blank"">Link</a>

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you were trying to use rc:LinkTarget

Comment: I think I misunderstood. https://localhost/reports/ReportViewer.aspx?repId=4&rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=_blank&rc:Zoom=Whole+Page

Answer (score 0):

Your link (I'm fairly sure) should look something like this

http://mySSRSServerName/ReportServer?/MyReportFolderName/MyReportName&rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=_blank

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. My example shows rc:LinkTarget, but your is rc:TargetLink. Has mine been misspelled?

Comment: Sorry, I was doing this on my phone, late at night ! LinkTarget is correct. My main point was that to open an SSRS report directly from a URL you need to be using the `http://mySSRSServerName/ReportServer?` route rather than the `ReportViewer.apsx`